# CSS3 Transition to not effect other elements?

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-transitions

Is it possible to have height transitions that don't affect the position of nearby elements?

This particular case involves divs with float:left.

Demo:
http://ashleystewart.me/

I'd like the hover transition to go on top of the element you can see moving around.

Comment: Could you post a minimal ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org)) demo on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com), or similar? That way it's easier for us to adjust your CSS to solve your problem without having to recreate a demo ourselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the container boxes Relative positioning and the fly-out details box Absolute positioning. Since Absolute positioned elements are removed from the layout, it wont interfere with the floats.

demo: http://dabblet.com/gist/3729269

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that in the current layout-logic you're following, it'd be very hard to fix.

Why? Because like your `floats` in the first row are aligned next to each other, when a box in the upper row is expanded on `:hover`, the `float`s in the bottom row will reposition relatively to that one as well.

Here's how I would go about achieving your idea:

- Don't use `float`ing, use something like `display: inline-block;`.
- Your semantic `article` wrappers are causing issues when using `inline-block;`. Either get rid of them (oops, might not be SEO friendly), or  make sure you aren't relying on `overflow: hidden;`  when styling your "boxes."

Sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position` property instead of using `float` property, you can do following:

```
#idname {
   position:fixed;
   margin-right:100px;
   margin-left:100px;
   margin-top:100px;
   margin-bottom:100px; /* I had written 100px only for example you can adjust it according to your screen */
}

#idname:hover {
   -moz-transtion: /* adjust the setting here for Firefox */;
   -webkit-transition: /* adjust the setting here for chrome and safari */;
   -o-transition: /* adjust the setting here for Opera */;
}
```

This will enable the moving of `div` and its position will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a transition on a transform  by using. Transform will change the element without effecting layout. You would want to use `transform: scaleY()` say you wanted to double the height of something:

```
transform: scaleY(2);
-webkit-transform: scaleY(2);
-moz-transform: scaleY(2);
-o-transform: scaleY(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `<div>` in a proper positioning.
Keep the outside ones in position:fixed and the inner ones in position:absolute

Or the other way is to make the maximum height fixed for the outer `<div>` and the inner `<div>` should be kept the maximum transformation height equal to the outer one. It will help in not making other `<div>` getting affected on transaction

Or the other way can be, use blocks to display the content, rather using float way

Answer (score -1):

You can use `position: absolute` instead of `position: fixed`, this way the div won't move when you open web developer tools.